# foreachを使ってRedBlackTreeの要素を列挙できるのは何故でしょうか

Tags: d

`RedBlackTree`の要素は、次のように`foreach`を使って列挙することができます。

```
auto t = new RedBlackTree!int;
// ...
foreach(elem; t) {
  // ...
}
```

ところで、一般に`foreach`で要素を列挙するためには

- `opApply`を定義
- `empty`, `front`, `popFront`を定義

のいずれかが必要だという認識なのですが、[ソースコード](https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/v2.088.0/std/container/rbtree.d)を見る限り、`RedBlackTree`は`opApply`も`popFront`も持っていないようです。

`RBRange`は2番目に挙げた3つのメソッドを持っていますが、`foreach`の`;`の右側に(`RBRange`ではなく)`RedBlackTree`を置ける理由が分かりません。

(コンパイラ: DMD 2.088.0)

Comment: [ここ](https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/v2.088.0/std/container/rbtree.d#L809)と[ここ](https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/v2.088.0/std/container/rbtree.d#L650)を見ると Range interface を実装しているので、foreach で iteration 処理が可能になっているのだと思います。

Comment: @metropolis  Range interfaceとは何でしょうか？`Range`という名前を見つけたら後はコンパイラが面倒を見てくれるといったことでしょうか。（`RBRange`のコンストラクタの引数もそれほど一般的な形をしていないので、そこまでできるのかなと思っています。）

Comment: 参考: [Ranges - Dlang Tour](https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/basics/ranges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結論から言うと、コンパイラが自動的に(引数を取らず、レンジを返す)`opIndex`または`opSlice`呼び出しに置き換えた上で処理を行ってくれるからでした。

したがって、次のようなコードを書くことができます。

```
//import std.stdio : writeln;

struct R {
    bool empty() {
        return false;
    }

    long front() {
        return 11111111;
    }

    void popFront() {
    }
}

class A {
    // opSliceの定義をコメントアウトすると、コンパイルエラー
    auto opSlice() {
        return R();
    }
}

void main() {
    auto a = new A;

    foreach (v; a) {
        //writeln(v);
    }
}
```

言語リファレンス[1](https://dlang.org/spec/statement.html)には、この機能について書かれた部分は見つけられませんでしたが、「The D Programming Language (TDPL)」には記述があるそうです[2](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5605)。

以下参考にしたリンクです。

ちょうどRedBlackTreeを例にして説明しています。
[User defined type and foreach - D Programming Language Discussion Forum](https://forum.dlang.org/post/mailman.189.1510830561.9493.digitalmars-d-learn@puremagic.com)

この機能が導入された経緯について言及しています
[When to opCall instead of opIndex and opSlice? - D Programming Language Discussion Forum](https://forum.dlang.org/post/mailman.291.1506972010.3410.digitalmars-d-learn@puremagic.com)